# Класс Math. Требуется вывести гипотенузу по теореме Пифагора

Tags: c#

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   

            Console.WriteLine("Привет! Я умею находить площадь треугольника s=...");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //ввод в консоль для переменной a;
            string a ="";
            Console.Write("Введите сторону a: ");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();           

            double a1;
            double.TryParse(a, out a1);

           //ввод в консоль для переменной b
            string b = "";
            Console.Write("Введите сторону b: ");
            b = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();


            double b1;
            double.TryParse(b, out b1);

            //вычисляем площадь            
            double s = a1 * b1 / 2;
            Console.WriteLine("Площадь треугольника = " + s);
            Console.WriteLine();


            //Нахождение гипотенузы по теореме Пифагора;
            Console.WriteLine("А также, находить длину гипотенузы по теореме Пифагора");
            Console.WriteLine();

            string katetA = "";
            Console.Write("Введите катет a: ");
            katetA = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            double katetA1;
            double.TryParse(katetA, out katetA1);


            string katetB = "";
            Console.Write("Введите катет b: ");
            katetA = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            double katetB1;
            double.TryParse(katetB, out katetB1);

            double c = (Math.Pow(katetA1, 2) + Math.Pow(katetB1, 2));
            Console.WriteLine("Гипотенуза равна = " + c);

        }
    }
}
```

В этом коде, при выводе гипотенузы, получается абракадабра. Что не так?

Comment: а что такое абракадабра? неверное значение или набор нечитаемых символов?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Выводился не верный результат во-втором пункте программы. При написании кода голова уже кипела от занятий. Вместо формулы a2*b2=c2 применил a2*b2=c. Когда осознал свою нелепую ошибку, уже получил пару дизлайков и, как обычно, полный доходчивый ответ от Vlada.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже вы забыли применить `Math.Sqrt`

Например,

```
double c = Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow( katetA1, 2) + Math.Pow( katetB1, 2 ) );
```

И у вас здесь опечатка

```
string katetB = "";
Console.Write("Введите катет b: ");
katetA = Console.ReadLine();
^^^^^^
```

Должно быть

```
string katetB = "";
Console.Write("Введите катет b: ");
katetB = Console.ReadLine();
^^^^^^
```

Comment: double c1 = Math.Pow(katetA1, 2) + Math.Pow(katetB1, 2);
            double c = Math.Sqrt(c1);
            Console.WriteLine("Гипотенуза равна = " + c.ToString());

Comment: @ВикторЕпифанов Смотрите добавление к моему ответу.

Comment: Спасибо, Влад! Поправил, все заработало.

Comment: @ВикторЕпифанов Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)